# Display number of li items on webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, html-lists, element

I have a

```
<ul id="listofitems"></ul>
```

in which I add li items using javascript.
I'd like to display the number of items inside the list at the top of my page, using javascript. How could I do that?

Answer (score 2):

While I would suggest that [Satpal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30153974/82548) is probably the one you should go for, you *could* do this - with some minor caveats - with purely CSS and HTML:

```css
#listofitems {
  /* the user-defined counter we're using
     to number the list-items within this list: */
  counter-reset: listCount;
}
#listofitems li {
  /* incrementing that counter in each <li>: */
  counter-increment: listCount;
}

#listofitems li:last-child::before {
  /* showing the counter: */
  content: counter(listCount);
  /* positioning it absolutely (this
     is the main caveat): */
  position: absolute;
  /* setting the position to show: */
  top: 0;
  right: 3em; /* just to move from behind the 'full screen'/'back' box */
  /* aesthetics, irrelevant to the demo
     adjust to taste: */
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul id="listofitems">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

As for the caveat, that's the problem with using `position: absolute` on an element in that it will be positioned relative to the first ancestor element with a `position` property-value set to anything other than `static` (the default), so if an ancestor has its position set to `relative`, `fixed`, `absolute` then it will cause the `li:last-child::before` pseudo-element to be positioned in relation to *that* element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to find element then get `length` property.

> `document.querySelectorAll` returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. The object returned is a NodeList.

*code*

```
document.querySelectorAll('#listofitems li').length
```

```js
window.onload = function() {

  alert(document.querySelectorAll('#listofitems li').length);

}
```

```html
<ul id='listofitems'>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I would add note of the narrow support of `querySelectorAll`

Comment: It's even available in IE from version 8 onwards; it's not that narrowly supported anymore.

Comment: thanks for your answer! But how do I add it to my webpage now? I don't want it to be an alert, I'd like it to be put in a div on my page.

Comment: @RoyMorinKat `document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('#listofitems li').length;`

Comment: @RoyMorinKat you ask a specific question and here's the answer. It's down to you to work this into your existing source code.

Answer (score 0):

**`document.getElementById` has *great support*, and is *significantly faster than `querySelectorAll`***. You can use this instead:

```
document.getElementById('list').getElementsByTagName('li').length;
```

This is supported from IE6+ and basically *every browser*.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementById('listofitems').getElementsByTagName('li').length;

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'They are ' + elements + ' li in the list';
};
```

```html
<ul id="listofitems">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>

<div id="result"></div>
```

---

### Why use this?

- This has [faster performance](http://jsperf.com/chained-document-getelementsbytagname-vs-document-query) *by a longshot*
  [image: Speed Tests]
- Support is no problem
  [image: Support Table]